# Xunit Testing an ActionResult

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am trying to write a unit test using Xunit and moq that will return a data from the client.GetAll().
        At the moment when I debug the client.GetAll just return null.

```
    This is my controller class

    private readonly IClient _client;
    public EventsController(IClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EventDTO>>> List()
    {
        var values = await _client.GetAll();

        return Ok(values);
    }
```

I am using my Client code implement. I am not sure if the IOptions is causing the issue

```
  public class Client: IClient
  {
    public RestClient RestClient { get; set; }
    public IOptions<MySettings>Settings { get; set; }
    public Client(IOptions<MySettings>options)
    {
        Settings = options;
        RestClient = new RestClient(options.Value.BaseUrl);
    }

    public async Task<List<EventDTO>> GetAll()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(Settings.Value.GetAll, Method.GET);
        var content = await RestClient.GetAsync<RootObject>(request);

        var data = content.Events.SelectMany(con =>
            con.Geometries.Select(geo =>
                new EventDTO
                {
                    Title = con.Title,
                    Id = con.Sources.FirstOrDefault()?.Id,
                    CategoriesTitle = con.Categories.FirstOrDefault()?.Title,
                    DateTime = geo.Date
                })
        ).ToList();

        return data;
    }
```

This is my test class. I noticed that when i debug it does not go into the _client.GetAll() method.
    Is this because I dont IOptionsoptions setup correctly?

```
public class EventsControllerTests
   {
    private readonly EventsController _controller;
    private readonly Mock<IClient> _clientService;
    public EventsControllerTests()
    {
        _clientService = new Mock<IClient>();
        _controller = new EventsController(_clientService.Object)
        {
            ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
            {
                HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
            }
        };
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_return_events_from_configured_service()
    {
        var response = new RootObject();
        {
            new Event()
            {
                Id = "sadsadsa"
            };
        };

        var s = _clientService.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(response);

        var controllerResponse = await _controller.List();

        var responseBody = controllerResponse.Value as IEnumerable<EventDTO>;
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: From a quick skim, your setup on the IClient mock is setting up a Get method, rather than GetAll `var s = _clientService.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(response);`, that would be a good reason why it doesn't enter GetAll and why you're getting null returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test your `GetAll` method separately from the controller. In the controller you can just mock your client.

```cs
public class EventsControllerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IClient> _clientMock;
    private readonly EventsController _testeeController;

    public EventsControllerTests()
    {
        _clientMock = new Mock<IClient>();
        _testeeController = new EventsController(_clientMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task ListTest()
    {
        var dtoList = new List<EventDto>{new EventDto(), new EventDto()};
        _clientMock.Setup(c => c.GetAll()).ReturnsAsync(dtoList);

        var response = await _testeeController.List();
        var jsonResult = (JsonResult) response.Result;
        var dtoListFromResponse = (IEnumerable<EventDto>) jsonResult.Value;

        // compare dtoListFromResponse with dtoList
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change the JsonResult to ObjectResult.